# New USB thumb drive gets stuck on transfer for seconds

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I have purchased this Imation 128 USB3.0 thumb drive today. I have copied a large file into it (15GB). The transfer went smoothly. Though, when I copied the file back from the thumb drive into my HDD, it got stuck around 1.5GB for 15-20 seconds then it continued until it copied the file.

The speed dropped from 105mb into 76mb, but the file got copied. Is this issue stuck issue common with thumb drives or do I have a faulty one?

Regards and thanks.

Comment: I think this drive is faulty. I have hashed the file several times and it is giving me a different hash each time I hash it.

Comment: Try

Changing USB port

Updating your device drivers .

Run Disk defragmenter on both drives

Run CHKDSK on both drives

Changing USB removal policy

Comment: Turns out the flash drive was indeed faulty.

Comment: It turns out the flash drive was bad.